# How to make MapReduce format more readable

Tags: mongodb

So i have written a MapReduce in Mongo that takes the weight and calculates the average for each

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {

   emit(this.gender, this.weight);
               };


var reduceFunction1 = function(keyGender, valuesWeight) {
                      return Array.avg(valuesWeight);
                  };

db.dragons.mapReduce(
                 mapFunction1,
                 reduceFunction1,
                 { out: "map_reduce_example" }
               )

db.map_reduce_example.find()
```

this all works well but the output of

```
_id : "F" : 72

_id : "M" : 90
```

Is a little bland, How can I make it produces something like the average 'f' weight is 72. No issue if you cant as the alteration is only something minimal benefit

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this output `_id : "F" : 72`?? This is invalid format

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yvbD9Vl.png this is the output